# How to create a hash from an array with repeated values

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-map

I am solving a problem , part of which requires me to convert an array into a hash table but the array might contain duplicates.

Now if there were no duplicates i could have simply done :-

```
unordered_map<int,int>hash;

for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
hash[arr[i]] = arr[i];
}
```

but I am not sure what to do in case of repeated keys and values.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you're hashing an int?

Comment: Is `hash[arr[i]] = arr[i]` what you are actually meaning to do here? If the value and the key are the same thing, why not use a `multiset` or `unodered_multiset`?

Comment: Is the purpose of your hash table *key* to be the ordinal of the array, or the value stored at that ordinal? It *looks* like you want to use the value. The answer to that is pretty important to how you do this. If the hashmap is simply keying on array value, than you can accumulate occurrence counts by simply `++hash[arr[i]];` in your loop rather than what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to achieve. Use `std::unordered_multimap`. Or count number of repetitions and store it in map's value.

Answer (score 0):

For non-trivial hashes; the instance that was hashed is usually stored along with the hash.

This allows the `==` or `<` to be tested post hash.  If there's a collision where `hash(a) == hash(b)` && `a != b`, then you either modify the hash so that the collision no longer exists, or have hash -> vector; or some combination of the 2.  Depends exactly what you want to use the hash for.